# Double integral - over general domain

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

[image]

The domain here is the rectangle $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$ and a region is cut out given by the semi circle $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

If the domain we are integrating over is then defined as $\Omega$ is $\int \int _{\Omega }f(x,y) \ dA$ given by $$\int_{-1}^{1} dx \int_{-1}^{1} f(x,y) \ dy -\int_{-1}^{1} dx\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{0} f(x,y) \ dy $$ or  $$\int_{-1}^{1} dx \int_{-1}^{1} f(x,y) \ dy +\int_{-1}^{1} dx\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{0} f(x,y) \ dy $$?

[The domain here is supposed to be the black rectangle with the blue semi circle cut out.]

Answer (score 0):

The first one, since you removing that volume from your calculation.